# Categorization of STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to become more familiar with STL algorithms, particularly I'm trying to divide them into categories, so far I have 'mutators' and 'inspectors':

Inspectors (do NOT produce side effect on the elements):

```
std::count_if();
std::includes();
std::find();
```

Mutators (do produce side effect on the elements):

```
std::transform();
std::sort();
std::replace();
std::for_each();
std::remove_if();
std::fill_n();
```

My Question:

1) Are the above categorisations correct? Have I missed any?

2) Are these the only two categories of STL algorithm?

Comment: [This algorithm reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) already have a nice category division. Might as well use it. :)

Comment: An algorithm either modifies something, or it retrieves something, or it does nothing. As the a latter category isn't included in STL, you're categories are correct and complete.

Comment: STL isn't what all of you think it is. You are talking about the c++ standard library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you read the `STL` *tag* the OP is using the term correctly.